# Удалить .css после добавления

Tags: javascript

подскажите есть вот такой скрипт

```
setTimeout(function(){
  $('.side-panel').css("right", "0")
  ;
},1000);
$(document).mouseup(function (e){  
  var div = $(".side-panel");  //класс элемента вне которого клик
  if (!div.is(e.target) ) {  
          div.css("right", "-360px");  
  }
});
```

как сделать чтобы сразу после добавления последнего стиля  он исчезал или очищался?

Comment: div.css("right", "") ? Если div изначально содержит какое-либо значение, то его нужно будет сохранить для дальнейшего восстановления.